# Is there any library to deserialize with python which is serialized with java

Tags: java, python, serialization

Is there any library to deserialize with python which is serialized with java?

Comment: Is your question referring to the java.io.Serializable protocol or some other mechanism of serialization?

Comment: I don't have control over the serialization. 
Serialization is done through java.io.Serialization. 
I don't want to use jython

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java serialisation is a representation of the class/data structures and tightly tied to the virtual machine. Consequently that's going to be difficult to translate to the Python world.

1. Your Java program can serialise/deserialise in XML, which would be translatable. Check out [JAXB](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/WebServices/jaxb/) or [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org)
2. Have you looked at the possibility of running in [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) - the Python implementation in Java

Answer (score 9):

Here's a very, very, rough implementation that doesn't require any imports. The tricky thing here is some classes have custom serializers which require the original code to deserialize. Also, my particular file was gzip'd though I didn't include code for that. I used these two pages for reference:

http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/2915
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

def parse(f):
    h = lambda s: ' '.join('%.2X' % ord(x) for x in s) # format as hex
    p = lambda s: sum(ord(x)*256**i for i, x in enumerate(reversed(s))) # parse integer
    magic = f.read(2)
    assert magic == '\xAC\xED', h(magic) # STREAM_MAGIC
    assert p(f.read(2)) == 5 # STREAM_VERSION
    handles = []
    def parse_obj():
        b = f.read(1)
        if not b:
            raise StopIteration # not necessarily the best thing to throw here.
        if b == '\x70': # p TC_NULL
            return None
        elif b == '\x71': # q TC_REFERENCE
            handle = p(f.read(4)) - 0x7E0000 # baseWireHandle
            o = handles[handle]
            return o[1]
        elif b == '\x74': # t TC_STRING
            string = f.read(p(f.read(2))).decode('utf-8')
            handles.append(('TC_STRING', string))
            return string
        elif b == '\x75': # u TC_ARRAY
            data = []
            cls = parse_obj()
            size = p(f.read(4))
            handles.append(('TC_ARRAY', data))
            assert cls['_name'] in ('[B', '[I'), (cls['_name'], size, f.read(50))
            for x in range(size):
                data.append(f.read({'[B': 1, '[I': 4}[cls['_name']]))
            return data
        elif b == '\x7E': # ~ TC_ENUM
            enum = {}
            enum['_cls'] = parse_obj()
            handles.append(('TC_ENUM', enum))
            enum['_name'] = parse_obj()
            return enum
        elif b == '\x72': # r TC_CLASSDESC
            cls = {'fields': []}
            full_name = f.read(p(f.read(2)))
            cls['_name'] = full_name.split('.')[-1] # i don't care about full path
            f.read(8) # uid
            cls['flags'] = f.read(1)
            handles.append(('TC_CLASSDESC', cls))
            assert cls['flags'] in ('\2', '\3', '\x0C', '\x12'), h(cls['flags'])
            b = f.read(2)
            for i in range(p(b)):
                typ = f.read(1)
                name = f.read(p(f.read(2)))
                fcls = parse_obj() if typ in 'L[' else ''
                cls['fields'].append((name, typ, fcls.split('/')[-1])) # don't care about full path
            b = f.read(1)
            assert b == '\x78', h(b)
            cls['parent'] = parse_obj()
            return cls
        # TC_OBJECT
        assert b == '\x73', (h(b), h(f.read(4)), f.read(50))
        obj = {}
        obj['_cls'] = parse_obj()
        obj['_name'] = obj['_cls']['_name']
        handle = len(handles)
        parents = [obj['_cls']]
        while parents[0]['parent']:
            parents.insert(0, parents[0]['parent'])
        handles.append(('TC_OBJECT', obj))
        for cls in parents:
            for name, typ, fcls in cls['fields'] if cls['flags'] in ('\2', '\3') else []:
                if typ == 'I': # Integer
                    obj[name] = p(f.read(4))
                elif typ == 'S': # Short
                    obj[name] = p(f.read(2))
                elif typ == 'J': # Long
                    obj[name] = p(f.read(8))
                elif typ == 'Z': # Bool
                    b = f.read(1)
                    assert p(b) in (0, 1)
                    obj[name] = bool(p(b))
                elif typ == 'F': # Float
                    obj[name] = h(f.read(4))
                elif typ in 'BC': # Byte, Char
                    obj[name] = f.read(1)
                elif typ in 'L[': # Object, Array
                    obj[name] = parse_obj()
                else: # Unknown
                    assert False, (name, typ, fcls)
            if cls['flags'] in ('\3', '\x0C'): # SC_WRITE_METHOD, SC_BLOCKDATA
                b = f.read(1)
                if b == '\x77': # see the readObject / writeObject methods
                    block = f.read(p(f.read(1)))
                    if cls['_name'].endswith('HashMap') or cls['_name'].endswith('Hashtable'):
                        # http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/java/util/HashMap.java.html
                        # http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/java/util/Hashtable.java.html
                        assert len(block) == 8, h(block)
                        size = p(block[4:])
                        obj['data'] = [] # python doesn't allow dicts as keys
                        for i in range(size):
                            k = parse_obj()
                            v = parse_obj()
                            obj['data'].append((k, v))
                        try:
                            obj['data'] = dict(obj['data'])
                        except TypeError:
                            pass # non hashable keys
                    elif cls['_name'].endswith('HashSet'):
                        # http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/java/util/HashSet.java.html
                        assert len(block) == 12, h(block)
                        size = p(block[-4:])
                        obj['data'] = []
                        for i in range(size):
                            obj['data'].append(parse_obj())
                    elif cls['_name'].endswith('ArrayList'):
                        # http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/java/util/ArrayList.java.html
                        assert len(block) == 4, h(block)
                        obj['data'] = []
                        for i in range(obj['size']):
                            obj['data'].append(parse_obj())
                    else:
                        assert False, cls['_name']
                    b = f.read(1)
                assert b == '\x78', h(b) + ' ' + repr(f.read(50)) # TC_ENDBLOCKDATA
        handles[handle] = ('py', obj)
        return obj
    objs = []
    while 1:
        try:
            objs.append(parse_obj())
        except StopIteration:
            return objs

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys, json
    json.dump(parse(sys.stdin), sys.stdout, indent=2)
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked with a small fix (`objs.append(parse_obj(''))` => `objs.append(parse_obj())`). I've edited your answer to improve that, and also to make it work as stdin=>stdout filter by default.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much for the bugfix. I merged in your stdin->stdout json idea too.

Comment: So much pro. Wow. Amaze.

Comment: Does this work with java 8-serialized files? I get an assert error.

Comment: Nice code, thank you very much! I've added some funcionality and a serializer and uploaded to github. You can see the code here: https://github.com/fonkap/java_deser.git

Answer (score 5):

Java binary serialization is really designed to be used with Java. To do it in Python you'd have to have all the relevant Java classes available for inspection, and create Python objects appropriately - it would be pretty hideous and fragile.

You're better off using a cross-platform serialization format such as Thrift, Protocol Buffers, JSON or XML. If you can't change which serialization format is used in the Java code, I'd suggest writing new Java code which deserializes from the binary format and then reserializes to a cross-platform format.

Answer (score 3):

You don't say whether you have control over the serialization of the data or not, but if you do, [JSON](http://json.org/) seems to be a nice format which is cross platform and has a good balance between human readable and machine readable.  [For java](http://json.org/java/) and [distributed with python](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html).

Comment: +1 Who downvoted this? The question is ambiguous and this is certainly a valid response. The OP doesn't give any description as to what is being serialized. I suppose you can assume that the OP is referring to java.io.Serializable, but he/she could just as easily be referring to some proprietary wire protocol.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd read the data with [Jython](http://www.jython.org/), and either reserialize it with `pickle` ( so that you can read it from Python ), or in a language neutral format, like XML.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java classes, then I don't even know what it would mean to deserialize a Java class in a Python environment.  If you are only using simple primitives (ints, floats, strings), then it probably wouldn't be too hard to build a Python library that could deserialize the Java format.

But as others have said, there are better cross-platform solutions.

Answer (score -1):

An other option is to use [Perspective Broker](http://twistedmatrix.com/projects/core/documentation/howto/pb-intro.html) from [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/). Their's a [Java implementation](http://itamarst.org/software/twistedjava/). If you just need serialisation/deserialisation you can use only [Banana](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.spread.banana.html) (protocol) or [Jelly](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.spread.jelly.html) (persistence) directly. Jelly is a S-expression-based persistence of objects.