# Producing an amqp message using python and consuming that same message using java

Tags: python, rabbitmq, amqp, pika, spring-amqp

**I am trying to produce an amqp message from python and consume that same message from java/spring.**

Here is my **producer** code (python):

```
import pika, sys, pickle

sys.path.append("trc/suivi/amqp")

from Person import Person

connection = pika.BlockingConnection()
channel = connection.channel()
me = Person("Juliano", 38)
pickled_me = pickle.dumps(me)
channel.basic_publish(exchange='', 
                      routing_key="myqueue",
                      body=pickled_me,
                      properties=pika.BasicProperties(delivery_mode=1))
```

Here is my **consumer** code (java):

```
ApplicationContext context = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/applicationContext.xml");
AmqpTemplate template = context.getBean(AmqpTemplate.class);
Person me = (Person) template.receiveAndConvert("myqueue");
System.out.println("Me: " + me.getName() + ":" + me.getAge());
```

Here is the java class for Person:

```
package trc.suivi.amqp;


import java.io.Serializable;

public class Person implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

}
```

and the corresponding python class:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
```

(located in **trc/suivi/amqp** directory structure)

I get a **class cast exception**. I am pretty sure this has to do either with the package/module name or with some serialization issue...

**EDIT**: I am now using JSon and I get this upon java deserialization:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConversionException: failed to convert Message content. Could not resolve
 __TypeId__ in header
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.DefaultJavaTypeMapper.retrieveHeader(DefaultJavaTypeMapper.java:104)
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.DefaultJavaTypeMapper.toJavaType(DefaultJavaTypeMapper.java:53)
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.JsonMessageConverter.fromMessage(JsonMessageConverter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.receiveAndConvert(RabbitTemplate.java:425)
    at trc.suivi.amqp.Consumer.main(Consumer.java:12)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using a common serialization library? Take a look at this answer for more details [Is there any library to deserialize with python which is serialized with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714624/is-there-any-library-to-deserialize-with-python-which-is-serialized-with-java).

You could try serializing into json and then it will be easy to deserialize that in your python code

Comment: Good point! I have updated my question. (I am actually doing the reverse: serialiazing in python and deserializing in java.)

Answer (score 2):

The key to this is using a standard message format which can be encoded and decoded in many languages. Many people just use JSON in UTF-8-encoded strings, but I have found MessagePack to be almost as flexible as JSON, and more bandwidth efficient. http://msgpack.org/

I like to use an object-style format because it is easy to add data to a message and then send it on to another queue. I have done that to deal with handling errors (by adding an error reason code and dispatching a message to a queue where the handler will examine the reason and either retry or fix and retry). Also, adding timestamps has been useful for charting transit times through the system. After handling a message (which will have timestamps from several previous steps), it is sent to a grapher which records the time in queue and time to handle for each step.