# Java Serialization to transfer data between any language

Tags: java, serialization

**Question:**

Instead of writing my own serialization algorithm; would it be possible to just use the built in Java serialization, like I have done below, while still having it work across multiple languages?

---

**Explanation:**

How I imagine it working, would be as follows: I start up a process, that will be be a language-specific program - written in that language. So I'd have a CppExecutor.exe file, for example. I would write data to a stream to this program. The program would then do what it needs to do, then return a result.

To do this, I would need to serialize the data in some way. The first thing that came to mind was the basic Java `Serialization` with the use of an `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream`. Most of what I have read has only stated that the Java serialization is Java-to-Java applications.

None of the data will ever need to be stored in a file. The method of transferring these packets would be through a [`java.lang.Process`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html), which I have set up already.

The data will be composed of the following:

- `String` - Mostly containing information that is displayed to the user.
- `Integer` - most likely 32-bit. Won't need to deal with times.
- `Float`- just to handle all floating-point values.
- `Character` - to ensure proper types are used.
- `Array` - Composed of any of the elements in this list.

The best way I have worked out how to do this is as follows: I would start with a 4-byte magic number - just to ensure we are working with the correct data. Following, I would have an integer specifying how many elements there are. After that, for each of the elements I would have: a single byte, signifying the data type (of the above), following by any crucial information, e.x: `length` for the `String` and `Array`. Then, the data that follows.

---

**Side-notes:**

I would also like to point out that a lot of these calculations will be taking place, where every millisecond could matter. Due to this, a text-based format (such as JSON) may produce far larger operation times. Considering that non of the packets would need to be interpreted by a human, using only bytes wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Have you looked into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714624/is-there-any-library-to-deserialize-with-python-which-is-serialized-with-java

Comment: IMHO The worst thing you can do here is reinvent the wheel. This is a case that has been thoroughly explored by others before, and the odds to create something as battle tested as Google's Protobuf are slim.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd recommend Google [protobuf](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/): it is binary, stable, proven, and has bindings for all languages you've mentioned. Moreover, it also handles structured data nicely.

Comment: Thank you for this! I might use it, then when I need to expand beyond Java, python and C++, I can just use this as a basis for my model.

Answer (score 3):

There is a binary json format called [bson](http://bsonspec.org/).

> I would also like to point out that a lot of these calculations will be taking place, so a text-based format (such as JSON) **may** produce far larger operation times.

---

> Do not optimize before you measured.
>   Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Can you have a try and benchmark the throughput? See if it fits your needs?

Comment: The way I see it, having a bunch of 'waste' would do no good. I'm the only person who will most likely ever read the packets and I can interpret bytes fine. I am also still in planning, so unless I want to rewrite a very large component for this program, I'd like to start on a solid basis.

Comment: So you question is like: "How bad is it to send much data between processes?" (I can not formulate is clearly) Inter-process-communication is quite fast. It does not even have to be a copy operation. The memory does not need to be copied if it is not modified by the receiver. The operating system with virtual memory would do this.

Comment: I have the problem that I can not answer otherwise because I do not know what 'start on solid basis', 'solid basis', what to 'rewrite', 'interpret bytes fine' means. That "The way I see it, having a bunch of 'waste' would do no good." Is twice opinionbased and not measurable. If you could go into detail with this and rework your question, you will have a chance of a new answer. Examples would be good, too. Which bytes are sent between the two processes in which usecase? This makes it easier to understand your goal.

Comment: Since your question did not receive enough attention do not be afraid to complete restructure it. Best of luck! Also comment on the code and what we see there.

Answer (score 1):

Thrift,Protobuf,JSON,MessagePack

complexity of installation Thrift >> Protobuf > BSON > MessagePack > JSON

serialization data size JSON > MessagePack > Binary Thrift > Compact Thrift > Protobuf

time cost Compact Thrift > Binary Thrift > Protobuf > JSON > MessagePack